# Модульное окно открывается только после 2х кликов

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Почему модульное окно открывается только после двойного клика?

Карточка товара:

```
<div class="quick-view card product-card-alt">
  <a class="view" data-id="{{$food->id}}" href="#quick-view" data-toggle="modal">
    <img style="border-radius:30px;" src="{{$food->img}}" title="Доставка {{$food->name}}" alt="Доставка {{$food->name}}">
    <div class="card-body">
    <h3 class="product-title font-size-sm mb-2">{{$food->name}}</h3>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-start pb-2">
    <p class="font-size-ms text-muted">{{$food->description}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="product-price">
    <span class="text-accent">{{$food->properties[0]->price}} ₽</span>
    @if($food->properties[0]->old_price)
    <del class="font-size-sm text-muted">{{$food->properties[0]->old_price}} ₽</del>
    @endif
    </div>
    </a>
  <div class="bg-faded-accent text-accent">
    <button class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="toast" data-target="#cart-toast" data-food-property-id="{{$food->properties[0]->id}}">В корзину<i class="czi-cart font-size-base ml-1"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Модульное окно:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.view', function(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const id = $(this).attr('data-id');

  $.ajax({
    url: `/api/food/${id}?show=true`,
    success: function(html) {
      //Wirte Quick view block to DOM
      $('body').prepend(html)
      $('#quick-view .slide-img_qv').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.big-img',
        focusOnSelect: true,
        appendArrows: $('.slide-img_qv'),
        adaptiveHeight: false,
        infinite: false,
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>',
      });
      // $('#quick-view-close-btn').on('click', function (event) {
      //     $('#quick-view').remove()
      // });
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="quick-view">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title product-title">{{$model->name}}</h4>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Product gallery-->
          <div class="col-lg-7 pr-lg-0">
            <div class="cz-product-gallery">
              <div class="cz-preview order-sm-2">
                <img src="{{$model->img}}" alt="Product image">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Product details-->
          <div class="col-lg-5 pt-4 pt-lg-0 cz-image-zoom-pane">
            <div class="product-details ml-auto pb-3">
              <div class="mb-3"><span class="h3 font-weight-normal text-accent mr-1">{{$model->properties[0]->price}} ₽</span> @if($model->properties[0]->old_price)
                <del class="h3 font-weight-normal text-muted">{{$model->properties[0]->old_price}} ₽</del> @endif
              </div>
              <div class="font-size-sm mb-4"><span class="text-muted">{{$model->description}}</span></div>
              <h5 class="h6 mb-3 py-2 border-bottom"><i class="czi-announcement text-muted font-size-lg align-middle mt-n1 mr-2"></i>Пищевая ценность на 100 г</h5>
              <ul class="font-size-sm pb-2">
                <li><span class="text-muted">Энерг. ценность: </span>{{$model->foodInfo->calories}}</li>
                <li><span class="text-muted">Белки: </span>{{$model->foodInfo->protein}}</li>
                <li><span class="text-muted">Жиры: </span>{{$model->foodInfo->fat}}</li>
                <li><span class="text-muted">Углеводы: </span>{{$model->foodInfo->carbohydrates}}</li>
                <li><span class="text-muted">Вес: </span>{{$model->foodInfo->weight}}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Работает на Bootstrap 4.

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас ошибка в названии параметра event, попробуйте сделать так и посмотреть решило ли это данную проблему:

```
$(document).on("click", ".view", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

вместо

```
$(document).on("click", ".view", function(e) { // --- e
  event.preventDefault() // --- event
})
```

Если нет, то добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) что бы его можно было запустить и посмотреть что с ним не так.